# Excel 2003 macro doesn't see named cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to clean up an excel macro where I was referencing cells directly ("LoopCount = Range("E4").Value") instead of using named cells ("LoopCount = Cell_LoopCount").

- So I named cell E4 "Cell_LoopCount".  Its label is right there in the upper left corner whenever I select cell E4.
- At the beginning of the macro, I added "Sheets("Data").Select" to make sure I'm operating on the right worksheet,
- But breaking after "LoopCount = Cell_LoopCount" reveals Cell_LoopCount is empty and LoopCount = 0
- "LoopCount = Range("E4").Value" still works fine

What obvious thing am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LoopCount = Range("Cell_LoopCount").Value

Comment: OK, I'm checking into the Serious Bonehead Treatment Center as soon as they have an opening.  Thanks.